# How would I read this data structure in Perl? Dictionary/Hash with keys containing lists containing lists. Python::Inline giving me errors

Tags: python, list, perl, hash, inline

I've been struggling for about 3 weeks on this simple issue. I can't understand why and I would give anything to solve it lol.

I am trying to read values from the data structure below. The docs say it's a dictionary with keys containing lists of results of that type.

Example: I get the master query reply using an eval function. I lookup the key "song_hits" to get that structure. Then I lookup the key 'track' and parse it. The problem is getting to the 'track' part.

When I do it from how Perl docs tell me to, I get Can't locate object method "FIRSTKEY" via package "Inline::Python::Object::Data".

So I'm wondering if there's a way to read the value using the eval function to bypass ObjectData's hash key limitation, another way to read it given I know exact keys, or if I'm just doing this entirely wrong.

```
{
'album_hits': [
{
    'album':
    {
        'albumArtRef': 'http://lh5.ggpht.com/DVIg4GiD6msHfgPs_Vu_2eRxCyAoz0fF...',
        'albumArtist': 'J.Cole',
        'albumId': 'Bfp2tuhynyqppnp6zennhmf6w3y',
        'artist': 'J.Cole',
        'artistId': ['Ajgnxme45wcqqv44vykrleifpji'],
        'description_attribution':
        {
            'kind': 'sj#attribution',
            'license_title': 'Creative Commons Attribution CC-BY',
            'license_url': 'http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode',
            'source_title': 'Freebase',
            'source_url': ''
        },
        'explicitType': '1',
        'kind': 'sj#album',
        'name': 'Work Out',
        'year': 2011
    },
    'type': '3'
}],
'artist_hits': [
{
    'artist':
    {
        'artistArtRef': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MJe-cDw9uQ-pUagoLlm...',
        'artistArtRefs': [
        {
            'aspectRatio': '2',
            'autogen': False,
            'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
            'url': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MJe-cDw9uQ-pUagoLlmKX3x_K...'
        }],
        'artistId': 'Ajgnxme45wcqqv44vykrleifpji',
        'artist_bio_attribution':
        {
            'kind': 'sj#attribution',
            'source_title': 'David Jeffries, Rovi'
        },
        'kind': 'sj#artist',
        'name': 'J. Cole'
    },
    'type': '2'
}],
'playlist_hits': [
{
    'playlist':
    {
        'albumArtRef': [
        {
            'url': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KJsAhrg8Jk_5A4xYLA68LFC...'
        }],
        'description': 'Workout Plan ',
        'kind': 'sj#playlist',
        'name': 'Workout',
        'ownerName': 'Ida Sarver',
        'shareToken': 'AMaBXyktyF6Yy_G-8wQy8Rru0tkueIbIFblt2h0BpkvTzHDz-fFj6P...',
        'type': 'SHARED'
    },
    'type': '4'
}],
'situation_hits': [
{
    'situation':
    {
        'description': 'Level up and enter beast mode with some loud, aggressive music.',
        'id': 'Nrklpcyfewwrmodvtds5qlfp5ve',
        'imageUrl': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Cd8WRMaG_pDwjTC_dSPIIuf...',
        'title': 'Entering Beast Mode',
        'wideImageUrl': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8A9S-nTb5pfJLcpS8P...'
    },
    'type': '7'
}],
'song_hits': [
{
    'track':
    {
        'album': 'Work Out',
        'albumArtRef': [
        {
            'aspectRatio': '1',
            'autogen': False,
            'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
            'url': 'http://lh5.ggpht.com/DVIg4GiD6msHfgPs_Vu_2eRxCyAoz0fFdxj5w...'
        }],
        'albumArtist': 'J.Cole',
        'albumAvailableForPurchase': True,
        'albumId': 'Bfp2tuhynyqppnp6zennhmf6w3y',
        'artist': 'J Cole',
        'artistId': ['Ajgnxme45wcqqv44vykrleifpji', 'Ampniqsqcwxk7btbgh5ycujij5i'],
        'composer': '',
        'discNumber': 1,
        'durationMillis': '234000',
        'estimatedSize': '9368582',
        'explicitType': '1',
        'genre': 'Pop',
        'kind': 'sj#track',
        'nid': 'Tq3nsmzeumhilpegkimjcnbr6aq',
        'primaryVideo':
        {
            'id': '6PN78PS_QsM',
            'kind': 'sj#video',
            'thumbnails': [
            {
                'height': 180,
                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6PN78PS_QsM/mqdefault.jpg',
                'width': 320
            }]
        },
        'storeId': 'Tq3nsmzeumhilpegkimjcnbr6aq',
        'title': 'Work Out',
        'trackAvailableForPurchase': True,
        'trackAvailableForSubscription': True,
        'trackNumber': 1,
        'trackType': '7',
        'year': 2011
    },
    'type': '1'
}],
'station_hits': [
{
    'station':
    {
        'compositeArtRefs': [
        {
            'aspectRatio': '1',
            'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
            'url': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3aD9mFppy6PwjADnjwv_w...'
        }],
        'contentTypes': ['1'],
        'description': 'These riff-tastic metal tracks are perfect for getting the blood pumping.',
        'imageUrls': [
        {
            'aspectRatio': '1',
            'autogen': False,
            'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
            'url': 'http://lh5.ggpht.com/YNGkFdrtk43e8H941fuAHjflrNZ1CJUeqdoys...'
        }],
        'kind': 'sj#radioStation',
        'name': 'Heavy Metal Workout',
        'seed':
        {
            'curatedStationId': 'Lcwg73w3bd64hsrgarnorif52r',
            'kind': 'sj#radioSeed',
            'seedType': '9'
        },
        'skipEventHistory': [],
        'stationSeeds': [
        {
            'curatedStationId': 'Lcwg73w3bd64hsrgarnorif52r',
            'kind': 'sj#radioSeed',
            'seedType': '9'
        }]
    },
    'type': '6'
}],
'video_hits': [
{
    'score': 629.6226806640625,
    'type': '8',
    'youtube_video':
    {
        'id': '6PN78PS_QsM',
        'kind': 'sj#video',
        'thumbnails': [
        {
            'height': 180,
            'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6PN78PS_QsM/mqdefault.jpg',
            'width': 320
        }],
        'title': 'J. Cole - Work Out'
    }
}]
```

}

Cleaned, but broken code with 3 weeks of different attempts: (I have tried for, foreach, while, but the furthest it would read would be either the entire unicode array, error, or an empty string)

```
sub search {
    my $query = shift;

    my $uri = 'googlemusic:search:' . $query;

    if (my $result = $cache->get($uri)) {
        return $result;
    }

    my $googleResult;
    my $result = {
        tracks => [],
        albums => [],
        artists => [],
    };        

    eval {
        $googleResult = $googleapi->search($query, $prefs->get('max_search_items'));
    };
    if ($@) {
        $log->error("Not able to search All Access for \"$query\": $@");
        return;
    }
    #gives not an ARRAY refernce error
    for my $hit (@{$googleResult->{song_hits}}) {
        push @{$result->{tracks}}, to_slim_track($hit->{track});
    }
    #works, but gives an error on the next line, 'newlist' object has no attribute 'album' 
    for my $hit ({$googleResult->{album_hits}}) {
        push @{$result->{albums}}, album_to_slim_album($hit->{album});
    }
    #Perl and others recommended way, but gives  Can't locate object method "FIRSTKEY" via package "Inline::Python::Object::Data"
    for my $hit (%{$googleResult->{artist_hits}}) {
        push @{$result->{artists}}, artist_to_slim_artist($hit->{artist});
    }

    # Add to the cache
    $cache->set($uri, $result, $CACHE_TIME);

    return $result;
}
```

I have tried reading up, but have gotten so many errors including:

- 'key' does not exist
- Can't use string ("track") as a HASH ref while strict refs in use
- Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref

My Full Test File: http://pastebin.com/DMnDc56i
GoogleApi PM (Python GAPI Hook): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hechtus/squeezebox-googlemusic/master/GoogleMusic/GoogleAPI.pm

Edit: Info, There were a couple of people who wanted unmaintained old code fixed, so I offered to help and got everything working besides this part.

Old Code Git: https://github.com/hechtus/squeezebox-googlemusic

Google Api Python I use: https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi

Comment: The quotes are screwed up in your source data. `’` should be `'`. You also have a random `2.1. Usage 19 gmusicapi Documentation, Release 10.0.1` and `20 Chapter 2. Using gmusicapi gmusicapi Documentation, Release 10.0.1` stuck in the middle there. Remove them first. You also have some lines that are split (1 key has two string values, one on each line) that will need to be repaired, and in case you hadn't noticed, some of your URLs are incomplete, like `'http://lh5.ggpht.com/YNGkFdrtk43e8H941fuAHjflrNZ1CJUeqdoys...'`.

Comment: Which module are you using?

Comment: There was a desire to bring back some old unmaintained code, so I have been adding fixes here and there to get it working. It's a squeezebox plugin that seems to be ran using perl with python code inside. It uses a python plugin that accesses google music's api. I added notes to my first. This specific section I believe uses Inline::Python Data Object

Comment: @CREW - I've been working on the same problem (google music plugin for squeezebox) for the past two hours; have you got anywhere? Is there any development discussion/hub for this? It would make sense for those who wanted to get this working to band together somehow...

Comment: @askvictor  With the data structure CREW figured out coming back from Python's object and posted here, there is now just JSON data and then the rest is straight Perl. See my post below.

Comment: @askvictor Yeah, I saw your post on the repo, I think that would be smart

Comment: @CREW - I've started a github team for this project at https://github.com/squeezebox-googlemusic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it that the data structure shown is in `$googleResult`. This is 'almost' `JSON` and you can process it as such using modules, after a simple cleanup. I will use [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm). The code below takes off after `$googleResult` has been acquired. (In tests I actually copied data shown in the question into a file and read it in.)  I first replace `'` by `"` and lower-case `True` and `False`, to get a valid JSON format which the module can decode.

```
# Other code from the question ...
use JSON::XS;

# For tests I loaded shown data into $googleResult (did not run this eval)
eval {
    $googleResult = $googleapi->search($query, $prefs->get('max_search_items'));
};
if ($@) {
    $log->error("Not able to search All Access for \"$query\": $@");
    return;
}

# The structure shown in the question needs a cleanup
# But this may be a road to madness, if there is more
$googleResult =~ s/'/"/g;        # ' turn off wrong editor coloring
$googleResult =~ s/False/false/g;
$googleResult =~ s/True/true/g;

my $coder = JSON::XS->new;    
# There are many options for how to set it up. Example:
# JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;    

my $data = $coder->decode($googleResult);  
# Now this is a normal Perl data structure that we can work with. 
# Look at what's under 'album_hits' for example
my $ralbhits = $data->{'album_hits'};  
print Dumper($ralbhits);
# We get: VAR1 = [ { 'album' => { albumID => ... } } ]
# Array reference, with nested hash references as the sole element

# Extract the 'artist'
my $artist = $ralbhits->[0]->{'album'}->{'artist'};
print "$artist\n";
```

This prints `J. Cole` (after the dump which I omit here). You can for convenience first extract a part of the structure and then query it far more simply. For example

```
# Get the hashref for album
my $ralbum = $ralbhits->[0]->{'album'};
my $artist = $ralbum->{'artist'};
```

Now once the data is unpacked you can retrieve what you need, based on what `artist_to_slim_artist()` needs and does. This is a normal data structure to work with.

Modules for JSON parsing return Perl data structures, see [Mapping in JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm#MAPPING).  Generally they will be nested, except in very simple cases. For how to work with them see [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), a cookbook on complex data structures.

---

The [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/) object given in this example, while invalid, needed very little correction. However, it may get far more complicated. For example, there is a far larger document (~`100kB`) linked to in a comment, with these problems.

- Name-value pairs are enclosed in `'` instead of `"` *and* the values themselves contain `'` (like `isn't` and other contractions), complicating the matching of `'` pairs.
- Invalid `u'` sequences at the beginning of names and values (`u` need be removed). This can be rolled together with the above, as they come together. There was also `u"`.
- Text may contain all kinds of escapes, for example some encoding of accents, which are not valid JSON. (One in that document.) This can be found and fixed (escaped for example).

It took a few minutes to come up with a few regex that corrected the document at the link, at close to 100kB in size, so that it parses cleanly with the above code. But the problem is that it is hard to tell what other trouble may be in the next document. Still, since this may be of interest here is the regex.

Instead of being enclosed in a pair of `"`, the names and values are in between `'`, and the leading one also has an extra char, `u'`. What makes it easier is that the closing `'` must be followed by either of `, : ] }` and I use positive lookahead to assert that.  Finally, there are some `u"` opening quotes and `u` is removed, first.

```
$googleResult =~ s/False/false/g;
$googleResult =~ s/True/true/g;
$googleResult =~ s/u"/"/g;
# There are also escaped characters in text, escape that backslash
$googleResult =~ s|(\\)|$1$1|g;
# Correct delimiters from u'...' to "...", see text below   
$googleResult =~ s/u'(.*?)' (?= []:},] )/"$1"/gx;
# We are good now, decode it
my $data = $coder->decode($googleResult); 
my $alb = $data->[0]{track}{album};
print "$alb\n";
```

This prints `These Things Happen` (correctly).  Above we capture between `u'` and the first `'` that is followed by either of  `]:,}` (for which a character class `[...]` is used). Then `u''` is replaced by `""`.  After this `decode($googleResult);` works and we get the Perl data structure to query.

There are various modules that allow a 'relaxed' approach and will accept many such irregularities. However, by using them we agree to use an invalid JSON, which is meant to be a simple and clear data format, and I wouldn't advise to go down that road. Note that the nearly full specification of the format fits nicely in one clear and genereously illustrated page at the above link. Also see [`JSON Example`](http://json.org/example.html), for a handful of examples.

I think that the best bet is to try to clean it up. Run a decoder like in the code above and see the error message. It will pinpoint the problem exactly. Then add a regex to correct that particular violation of format. Then go again. If the various documents you may work with carry more or less the same set of problems (like the ones above for example) it may well work. Or it may turn out that it is too much trouble, if new violations keep coming up, in which case you may need a different approach.

Finally, I don't know how you arrived at this format from the original Python-object problem. Could it be that the format got broken somewhere in translation? I don't see how that would be the case. Is it actually not meant to be JSON? However, it is  too close to it for that.

Is it possible to ask for valid JSON to be provided?

Comment: Wow, this makes a lot of sense. I artist_to_slim_artist puts the data in a format 'slimbox' can read to show on it's web UI. Example [Full File]]: http://pastebin.com/DMnDc56i

Comment: I'm going to try and put it together in a few hours after I wake. Thanks a lot for putting this in the right direction, I'm excited to try new ground. I'll be back in the morning.

Comment: @CREW  Well, it's great that you cleaned up those python objects (from your previous post) -- now you have JSON. That's known, clear and workable.

Comment: @CREW When you say "_artist-to-slim-artist puts the data in a format 'slimbox'_" -- what does that return? A single object of some sort?  (I looked at your link but can't read through all of that now.)  If it's just one thing returned I'l add code to put it on the array etc, if you need that.

Comment: Yeah, it returns an array of individual track information. But I'm still having issues getting to that part lol. I think our stackoverflow thread has caught others attention too. JSON is unable to parse the native results that the gmusicapi returns because it doesn't return a correct JSON format apparently. I think the changes that were made here to fix the JSON would have to be done programatically first.

Comment: Right now, when I read each 'key' like we did (ex: song_hits, playlist_hits, etc), I can get a reply in the format [{u'track':{u'artref':[{u'url':u'http:...'}]}}], but I can't get any further. Reading the track key like I'm supposed to gives Python::Inline errors about not being able to access a first key. So my options are to either figure out how to manually access the 'track' structure without using keys (Bypass Python::Inline issues), or turn it into another data structure to parse (like JSON corrected, or something else)

Comment: A returned example of the complex data structure which I can't figure out how to read without getting Python::Inline errors: http://pastebin.com/raw/tincMpwQ

Comment: @CREW  Oh ... that's some butchered JSON. (May unicode origin have something to do with it?) I don't know that messing with Python::Inline would help with that. You got it out of that object and that is good, that's what was burried inside I guess. Now you need to fix it.  However, that's a completely different question, at this point. I'd suggest that you wrap this up here and then you can post a question on 'How to fix a broken JSON' or some such. (State the background of the problem.) I'll add comments to my post shortly, to articulate this. Will let you know when it's up.

Comment: @CREW  I actually managed to clean up that (strictly speaking invalid) JSON from your link.  It's very telling, what kinds of things come up.  Can't post that here since it is really unrelated to this question, but will add to the upcoming comment.

Comment: Interesting, from the latest pastebin correct? Yeah, I originally thought it was unicode issues then realized small other things were returned as well strange

Comment: @CREW Yes, from that.  I will add a fat comment on bad JSON, just been tied up here.

Comment: @CREW  I have no idea whether you have any use of this, but I've added to the post the regex that cleans up that 100Kb document you linked in a comment above.  Just letting you know.  (Btw, I don't like what I see when I `Data::Dumper` it -- there are again those Python classes.  It seems that they are nested or so.  But, the document parses cleanly.)

Comment: I think this is barking up the wrong tree; $googleResult isn't a string, but a data structure returned by Inline Python code. So treating it as JSON code won't work, unless you can first convert the structure into text, the mangle it, then read it back in as a Perl structure. I've created a smaller sample program at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937897/how-do-i-use-or-convert-or-view-inline-python-objects-in-perl

Comment: @askvictor  We've all always agreed on the origin of data. I don't know whether you followed this problem -- there had been a previous question along the lines of what you're saying.  Somehow CREW did convert that to JSON, and this now is strictly about JSON data.  In _this_ question `$googleResult` is as shown, slightly broken JSON. The question of how it was converted remain, and I mention that.  As for your own recent question, it is eerily similar to a previous question by CREW, which this is a follow-up on.  Perhaphs ask CREW how they converted it to JSON.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @askvictor  If you are talking about the latest addition -- I looked at a linked file and saw JSON-like data -- and cleaned it up so that a JSON parser can read it.  This worked well and now you can nicely work with it as Perl data structure.  The catch: it seems to again have Python objects, burried as values in this piece of JSON data, here or there.  So perhaps the original conversion, that led to this question, didn't work fully on that big file, or just can't deal with nested objects.  I mention all this. If you have a way to convert correctly I think that CREW may be very interested.

Comment: @askvictor  Are you saying that this isn't meant to be JSON, not even broken, but a Python dict?  But then isn't it broken even worse ...? (My Python's a little rusty.)  In the linked file there are yet other extra things, which I can't associate with Python data structures at all.

Comment: @zdim: correct; it's a python structure (a dict of lists of dicts of etc etc). It originates from a JSON reponse from an server, but the gmusicapi puts it into a Python structure, which the Inline Python perl module should convert into a Perl structure.

Comment: @zdim (sorry, didn't see the 1st three comments; only responded to most recent :) The code in this question doesn't convert the python response to JSON or a string as far as I can see; it is basically the code from the unmaintained project. I can't see any code here, nor linked questions that use a string representation of the data. One approach would certainly be to use JSON as an intermediary, but there are much cleaner ways than mangling a Python-structure-as-a-string into JSON.

Comment: @askvictor Well, right, there is no conversion here -- the Inline Python object was evident in the previous question and I meant to say that I thought that the _data_ shown is (slightly invalid) JSON. I didn't realize that it is a python structure right as it stands, thank you.  But still, if this is what need be handled by Perl, I don't know how to do it otherwise. Some Inline Python code ... but that has got us all here :)  Also, the pastebin document in a comment in this thread has stuff which can't be Python (`u'...'`, and others).  So apparently it's all (even) worse than it seems.

Comment: FWIW in python, a unicode string is represented as u'String in here' i.e. the character u sits before the opening quote. In python 3 everything is unicode by default, so increasing numbers of libraries are using unicode by default.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this isn't really an answer, but out of the goodness of my heart I cleaned up your data for you. Here is a real Python dict. I don't know if some of the numerical string values should be ints or not, so I didn't mess with them. It'll be up to you to figure out what to do with the truncated URLs.

Another way to go about this would be to change `True` to `true`, `False` to `false`, and parse the dict as JSON.

```py
{
    'album_hits': [
    {
        'album':
        {
            'albumArtRef': 'http://lh5.ggpht.com/DVIg4GiD6msHfgPs_Vu_2eRxCyAoz0fF...',
            'albumArtist': 'J.Cole',
            'albumId': 'Bfp2tuhynyqppnp6zennhmf6w3y',
            'artist': 'J.Cole',
            'artistId': ['Ajgnxme45wcqqv44vykrleifpji'],
            'description_attribution':
            {
                'kind': 'sj#attribution',
                'license_title': 'Creative Commons Attribution CC-BY',
                'license_url': 'http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode',
                'source_title': 'Freebase',
                'source_url': ''
            },
            'explicitType': '1',
            'kind': 'sj#album',
            'name': 'Work Out',
            'year': 2011
        },
        'type': '3'
    }],
    'artist_hits': [
    {
        'artist':
        {
            'artistArtRef': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MJe-cDw9uQ-pUagoLlm...',
            'artistArtRefs': [
            {
                'aspectRatio': '2',
                'autogen': False,
                'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
                'url': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MJe-cDw9uQ-pUagoLlmKX3x_K...'
            }],
            'artistId': 'Ajgnxme45wcqqv44vykrleifpji',
            'artist_bio_attribution':
            {
                'kind': 'sj#attribution',
                'source_title': 'David Jeffries, Rovi'
            },
            'kind': 'sj#artist',
            'name': 'J. Cole'
        },
        'type': '2'
    }],
    'playlist_hits': [
    {
        'playlist':
        {
            'albumArtRef': [
            {
                'url': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KJsAhrg8Jk_5A4xYLA68LFC...'
            }],
            'description': 'Workout Plan ',
            'kind': 'sj#playlist',
            'name': 'Workout',
            'ownerName': 'Ida Sarver',
            'shareToken': 'AMaBXyktyF6Yy_G-8wQy8Rru0tkueIbIFblt2h0BpkvTzHDz-fFj6P...',
            'type': 'SHARED'
        },
        'type': '4'
    }],
    'situation_hits': [
    {
        'situation':
        {
            'description': 'Level up and enter beast mode with some loud, aggressive music.',
            'id': 'Nrklpcyfewwrmodvtds5qlfp5ve',
            'imageUrl': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Cd8WRMaG_pDwjTC_dSPIIuf...',
            'title': 'Entering Beast Mode',
            'wideImageUrl': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/8A9S-nTb5pfJLcpS8P...'
        },
        'type': '7'
    }],
    'song_hits': [
    {
        'track':
        {
            'album': 'Work Out',
            'albumArtRef': [
            {
                'aspectRatio': '1',
                'autogen': False,
                'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
                'url': 'http://lh5.ggpht.com/DVIg4GiD6msHfgPs_Vu_2eRxCyAoz0fFdxj5w...'
            }],
            'albumArtist': 'J.Cole',
            'albumAvailableForPurchase': True,
            'albumId': 'Bfp2tuhynyqppnp6zennhmf6w3y',
            'artist': 'J Cole',
            'artistId': ['Ajgnxme45wcqqv44vykrleifpji', 'Ampniqsqcwxk7btbgh5ycujij5i'],
            'composer': '',
            'discNumber': 1,
            'durationMillis': '234000',
            'estimatedSize': '9368582',
            'explicitType': '1',
            'genre': 'Pop',
            'kind': 'sj#track',
            'nid': 'Tq3nsmzeumhilpegkimjcnbr6aq',
            'primaryVideo':
            {
                'id': '6PN78PS_QsM',
                'kind': 'sj#video',
                'thumbnails': [
                {
                    'height': 180,
                    'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6PN78PS_QsM/mqdefault.jpg',
                    'width': 320
                }]
            },
            'storeId': 'Tq3nsmzeumhilpegkimjcnbr6aq',
            'title': 'Work Out',
            'trackAvailableForPurchase': True,
            'trackAvailableForSubscription': True,
            'trackNumber': 1,
            'trackType': '7',
            'year': 2011
        },
        'type': '1'
    }],
    'station_hits': [
    {
        'station':
        {
            'compositeArtRefs': [
            {
                'aspectRatio': '1',
                'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
                'url': 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3aD9mFppy6PwjADnjwv_w...'
            }],
            'contentTypes': ['1'],
            'description': 'These riff-tastic metal tracks are perfect for getting the blood pumping.',
            'imageUrls': [
            {
                'aspectRatio': '1',
                'autogen': False,
                'kind': 'sj#imageRef',
                'url': 'http://lh5.ggpht.com/YNGkFdrtk43e8H941fuAHjflrNZ1CJUeqdoys...'
            }],
            'kind': 'sj#radioStation',
            'name': 'Heavy Metal Workout',
            'seed':
            {
                'curatedStationId': 'Lcwg73w3bd64hsrgarnorif52r',
                'kind': 'sj#radioSeed',
                'seedType': '9'
            },
            'skipEventHistory': [],
            'stationSeeds': [
            {
                'curatedStationId': 'Lcwg73w3bd64hsrgarnorif52r',
                'kind': 'sj#radioSeed',
                'seedType': '9'
            }]
        },
        'type': '6'
    }],
    'video_hits': [
    {
        'score': 629.6226806640625,
        'type': '8',
        'youtube_video':
        {
            'id': '6PN78PS_QsM',
            'kind': 'sj#video',
            'thumbnails': [
            {
                'height': 180,
                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6PN78PS_QsM/mqdefault.jpg',
                'width': 320
            }],
            'title': 'J. Cole - Work Out'
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a solution using a list comprehension like so:

```
use Inline::Python qw(py_eval);

my $song_hits = py_eval("[x for x in $googleResult->{song_hits}]", 0);
for my $hit (@$song_hits) {
    push @{$result->{tracks}}, to_slim_track($hit->{track});
}
```

The commit is at:
https://github.com/squeezebox-googlemusic/squeezebox-googlemusic/commit/e6fa62d9da3bc7295023283ef5d25698737e5772