# How do I use (or convert, or view) inline Python objects in Perl?

Tags: python, perl

I'm resurrecting some orphaned code, which is written in Perl but uses inline Python. A call to the Python module returns an array of dicts or Python objects. I'm really struggling with how to access the data structures within - if I try to straight out log (print) the data structure, it appears to give the data fine, but if I index the top level array (or iterate in a list) it tells me the it's not an array reference. If I try use Dumper on the object I get:

```
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = '140162464462376')}, 'Inline::Python::Object' );
```

Any ideas how I can use (or convert) this object?

EDIT: sample code is below. This requires a Google Music account, installing the gmusicapi python module (for they python side; obviously inline python for the perl side). Interestingly, I wrote some python code and dumped into the Inline Python section only the data structure that the API call returned - it worked fine (see https://gist.github.com/askvictor/119c24b6fc46a77b349b307457e1a027 ). When I actually put the API call into the Inline Python section, it breaks at line 4 with `Not an ARRAY reference at sample.pl line 4.`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = search("radiohead");
print "$data\n";
print "$data->{song_hits}\n";
print "$data->{song_hits}[0]\n";
for my $hit (@{$data->{song_hits}}){
    print "$hit->{track}->{title}\n";
}

use Inline Python => <<'END_OF_PYTHON_CODE';
import gmusicapi

USERNAME="my_username@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="sooper_secr3t"
DEVICE_ID = "12345abcde123" # this can be obtained using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/squeezebox-googlemusic/squeezebox-googlemusic/master/mobile_devices.py
def search(needle):
    c = gmusicapi.Mobileclient()
    c.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DEVICE_ID)
    r = c.search(needle, 2)
    return r
END_OF_PYTHON_CODE
```

Comment: Those objects follow the [inside-out pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inside-Out-objects). You need to use their interface, which is unfortunately not that easy to guess. Can you create a [mcve] with a tiny bit of Python code that produces this output in Perl so we can try?

Comment: @simbabque Thanks; have added sample code. Interestingly, if I throw only the data structure that the code returns in the Inline section, it works fine, but if it runs the code as shown, it breaks.

Comment: Does your code not have `strict` and `warnings`?

Comment: The real code did; didn't bother with the sample code. Is there now, but makes no difference. Dumping the straight data structure as per https://gist.github.com/askvictor/119c24b6fc46a77b349b307457e1a027 works

Comment: I think this boils down to knowing how to dump those data structures. See https://metacpan.org/source/NINE/Inline-Python-0.49/Python.pm#L311 to how those works. Try dereferencing and Dumping that. `print Dumper \%$data`

Comment: In your gist it's not an object any more, it's just a data structure.

Comment: It's the deeper structures that I can't get to $data->{song_hits}[0] (sorry, my perl is very, very rusty)

Comment: @simbabque - the data passed from the Python Code _is_ just a data structure; not an object (`type(r)` returns `dict`). In any case, is there a way (in perl) to freeze or evaluate the data returned from Python so that it can function like the data structure shown in the gist? Thanks for all the suggestions btw!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115258/discussion-between-askvictor-and-simbabque).

Comment: I wrote stuff in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working through a 'useless' list comprehension inside a `py_eval()`. It seems that Perl's Inline Python doesn't handle lists of the type `future.types.newlist.newlist` that are returned from the python code. So this code converts those into plain old lists, which Perl can then handle.

```
my $song_hits = py_eval("[x for x in $data->{song_hits}]", 0);
for my $hit (@$song_hits) {
    print $hit->{track}->{title};
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you got it!  Btw, `song_hits` needs a dollar sign in front, for `$song_hits`.